# How to display specific items from an ArrayList based on a value from another ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, jcombobox

I'm currently carrying out a task, where I have to create a software development solution to allow managers to add new staff and tasks. for this, I have an `ArrayList` called `staffMembers`, which takes name, grade and salary as parameters and an array list called `tasksToDo`, which takes `taskName`, `taskGrade` and `taskHours` as parameters.

One of the requirements is to enable the managers to click a `JButton` and this will only display `staffMembers` whose grade is equal to or greater than the taskGrade for the selected task (this is selected using `JComboBox`). the result will be displayed in a `JTable`.

```
private void jButtonSelectTaskActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

    int num1 = this.jobGrade;//use the int supplied 
    //by user
    String[] colNames = {"Name", "Grade", "Montlhly Salary/Hourly Rate"};
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) staffByTaskGradeTable.getModel();

    Object rowData[][] = new Object[staffMembers.size()][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < staffMembers.size(); i++) {
        if (staffMembers.get(i).grade > num1) {

            rowData[i][0] = staffMembers.get(i).name;
            rowData[i][1] = staffMembers.get(i).grade;
            rowData[i][2] = staffMembers.get(i).getCost();

            model.setDataVector(rowData, colNames);
        }
    }
```

However, the code above doesn't give the required result and I hoped someone my be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: What result does it give?

Comment: Share the results of your code and add an actual question.

Comment: It gives me a list of all staff, including those whose grade is less than the job grade

Comment: Where exactly is `this.jobGrade` and what value does it have (initially and possibly reassigned)?

Comment: @deHaar this.jobGrade takes the value from the tasksToDo ArrayList once the task is created

Comment: `It gives me a list of all staff` - So what debugging did you do? Do you display the values of the "grade" and "num1" to see what you are comparing? Only you have the access to your data. Only you can determine why all the data is added to the model.

Comment: @camickr yes, these values are displayed in other tables which gather the same data and sort it by said values. If I select a task which requires a grade 9, it still returns all staff who are grade 8 and lower

Comment: `these values are displayed in other tables` - I don't care about other tables. I care about the If statement that is creating the data for this table. `If I select a task which requires a grade 9, it still returns all staff who are grade 8 and lower` - so you need to display those values immediately before your "if condition" to see exactly what you are comparing!!! Only  you can verify the data you are comparing is what you expect it to be. This is basic debugging!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting  model.setDataVector each time you get a match. Besides, `(sm.grade > num1)` must have >= comparing, if you want **equal or greater** grade.

Also, you shouldn't use get(i) multiple times, do it once and store in a variable for any further actions. Or just use forEach.(Or lambda if You use java8+)

```
private void jButtonSelectTaskActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

int num1 = this.jobGrade;//use the int supplied 
//by user
String[] colNames = {"Name", "Grade", "Montlhly Salary/Hourly Rate"};
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) staffByTaskGradeTable.getModel();

List<Object[]> rowData = new ArrayList<>();
Object[] member;
for (StaffMember sm:staffMembers) {
    if (sm.grade >= num1) {
        rowData.add(new Object[] {(Object)sm.name, (Object)sm.grade, 
                 (Object)sm.getCost()});
    }
}
model.setDataVector(rowData.toArray(new Object[rowData.size()][]), colNames);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. However, I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object rowData[][] = new Object[staffMembers.size()][3];
for (int i = 0; i < staffMembers.size(); i++) {
    if (staffMembers.get(i).grade > num1) {

        rowData[i][0] = staffMembers.get(i).name;
        rowData[i][1] = staffMembers.get(i).grade;
        rowData[i][2] = staffMembers.get(i).getCost();

        model.setDataVector(rowData, colNames);
    }
}
```

Don't use code like the above. You are reserving space in your 2D array assuming all staff members are selected. What if only the first and last meet your criteria? You will have a bunch of empty lines in the middle of the table.

Instead you should just dynamically add a row of data to the model when your specific criteria is met. Something like:

```
String[] colNames = {"Name", "Grade", "Montlhly Salary/Hourly Rate"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0); // create empty model


for (int i = 0; i < staffMembers.size(); i++) {
    if (staffMembers.get(i).grade > num1) {
        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(3);
        row.add( staffMembers.get(i).name );
        row.add( staffMembers.get(i).grade );
        row.add( staffMembers.get(i).getCost() );
        model.addRow( row );
    }
}

staffByTaskGradeTable.setModel( model );
```

You still need to debug why your "if condition" doesn't do what you expect.

Or how do you know that you are replacing the data in the model of the table that is visible on the frame. Maybe you have to instance of the table and only one is visible on the frame. A simple test it to just replace all the code in your method with:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(5, 5); 
staffByTaskGradeTable.setModel(model);
```

Now you should see an empty table with 5 row and 5 columns. If this works the problem is with your "if condition". The data is not what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think my issue is getting the value of jobGrade when selecting it in the jComboBox. Assuming that the objects are converted to strings and I am trying to get an int value. Does that make sense? My terminology isn't the best as I'm relatively new and just learning the basics of Swing

Comment: `Assuming that the objects are converted to strings` - why would it be converted to a string? If the value is an int then it should be stored in your object as an int so you can do comparison with your "num1" variable which is an int. If your object stores the value as a string then you first need to convert it to an int by using the `Integer.parseInt(...)` method.